# How to change selected item of listbox when clicking on the Button / textbox in ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

in a WPF project I have a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a set of items. I use a `DataTemplate` in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox` to represent the UI of these items.

What I want to happen is that when the user clicks into *any* part of the DataTemplate for a bound item then the `ListBox.SelectedItem` is set to the item whose `DataTemplate` it is. Then the selected `Style` will be applied. As you can see from the sample code below, clicking on Label is fine. However, controls such as `Button` and `TextBox` do not behave as wanted and there are no doubt others too. I suspect it's got something to do with focus.

How might I achieve this?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewSelectionOverride.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewSelectionOverride"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border
                    Name="Border"
                    Padding="2"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="itemTemplateBorder">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Margin="3,3,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Label"/>
                        <Button Margin="3,3,3,0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Button"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="3,3,3,0" Grid.Row="2" Text="TextBox"/>
                        <CheckBox Margin="3,3,3,0" Grid.Row="3" Content="CheckBox"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Dummy items to generate 4 items in ListBox
        DataContext = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `Border` element in the template and explicitly select the corresponding item:

```
private void Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Border border = sender as Border;
    lvv.SelectedItem = border.DataContext;
}
```

---

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Hi @mm8, thanks for the reply. Works great!  Cheers. Wondering if there was a XAML only solution to avoid code behind?